# Creating a Countdown Timer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, timer, countdown

I have wrote this code which counts down to a specific date.

How would I make it so that each element of the countdown is shown in a separate label.

So I would have a label that shows the number of days, a label to show the number of hours, a label to show the number of minutes and a label to show the number of seconds.

Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var dateLabelOutlet: UILabel!

let currentDate = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

let userCalendar = Calendar.current

let requestedComponent: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.day,.hour,.minute,.second]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(printTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    timer.fire()

}

func printTime()
{
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss"
    let startTime = Date()
    let endTime = dateFormatter.date(from: "25/12/16 00:00:00")
    let timeDifference = userCalendar.dateComponents(requestedComponent, from: startTime, to: endTime!)

    dateLabelOutlet.text = "\(timeDifference.day!) Days \(timeDifference.hour!) Hours \(timeDifference.minute!) Minutes \(timeDifference.second!) Seconds"
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: Since you have already separated the components, create the missing 3  labels and assign the components respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code already calculates the difference in `DateComponents`, and then builds a string with the day, hour, minute and second differences combined.

Just change this line:

```
dateLabelOutlet.text = "\(timeDifference.day!) Days \(timeDifference.hour!) Hours \(timeDifference.minute!) Minutes \(timeDifference.second!) Seconds"
```

You'll need to create 4 labels and put `timeDifference.day` in one, `timeDifference.hour` in another, `timeDifference.minute` in the third, and `timeDifference.second` in the 4th label.

If you wrote that code I would think that would be obvious - or is that somebody else's code that you copy/pasted?

Comment: thanks i tried this earlier but i got an error which caused the simulator to crash every time I loaded the app. but this time it worked

Comment: Ok, that's a separate problem. When you have problems like that, things to try are to quit Xcode and the simulator and restart them both, or to select "clean" from the project menu.